# Xamarin.Forms/Auth - Mobile Application , What kind of Server API is recommended?

Tags: php, rest, mobile, xamarin

I'm just wondering if there are any good / more reliable framework for server side using Xamarin Forms & Xamarin.Auth.

I was planning to use REST and maybe Lumen , which is a php micro framework but i'm not sure how compatible it is with Xamarin.Auth etc...

Tried to google it but interestingly , came up with nothing .

I basically want to register/sign in users from the app to the server , save their info and make REST api requests based on them.

I'm wondering if anyone had any experience with lumen & xamarin  or if there are other better choices that are more compatible .

Comment: I am also looking into something similar. info on this seems to be really sparse

Answer (score 0):

I've been researching different sites and forums for a proper back-end architecture for my cross-platform app. It's a turned-based game using Xamarin with a dedicated webserver and PHP serving as the application layer. 
I recommend checking out this post which has a lot of responses from seasoned pros, be sure to scroll down the thread:

```
http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/24549/php-mysql-with-json-and-webrequest
```

Your approach using REST is solid and appears to be the industry standard for mobile devices to access some type of database. Lumen looks promising given it's a framework designed for building APIs on PHP. OAuth2 is supported on Lumen which is supported by Xamarin.Auth. +1

Here's some good food for the brain:

- https://esbenp.github.io/2015/05/26/lumen-web-api-oauth-2-authentication/
- https://medium.com/omarelgabrys-blog/building-restful-apis-with-lumen-and-oauth2-8ba279c6a31#.if5nu88p3

You are on the right track. Good luck and Godspeed.